# Customizing Badge Label within the moreNavigationController

Tags: ios, uitabbar, badge

I use the badgeValue Attribute of tabBarItems to indicate a warning. This works fine as long as the tabBarItem is visible in the Tab Bar. See Picture:

[Looking good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4LHw.png)

But once the tabBarItem is moved behind the moreNavigationController the badgeValue turns into a Label that is part of a TableViewCell. Unfortunately due to the dark theme of the app the Label looks wrong with its white background. See Picture:

[ugly badge label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pw3P.jpg)

Is there a way to customize the color (textColor and backgroundColor) of this Label?

Thanks
Gerald